# How to remove new line between quotes and hex value delimiter by Linux command?

Tags: regex, linux

How to remove new line between quotes and hex value delimiter? This data 2 is always inside quotes

Example data:

```
data1 HEX "This data2 should be
in the same
line" HEX data3
```

Ideal output:

```
data1 HEX  "This data2 should be in the same line" HEX data3
```

The `HEX` represents the 13 hex value delimiter.
Please suggest linux command. Thanks

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and show us what you tried, since regex questions without attempts is considered off-topic.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: `perl -0777pe 's{(HEX) ".*?" $1}{ y/\n/ /sr }egs' inputfile` ?

Comment: By use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`\R+(?=[^"]*" HEX\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/Q96H7X/2) ([bash demo](https://tio.run/##HY27CgIxFER/ZUgTH4T4KFLJVoK1WAhGIXEvJhDvLmbt/PeYbDcHZs54l0Mp9AwDFEH2bnLwyVluaYvT8QpxCTGj8Q45DN/Uw5PlyJgCIbt3hRSZxNxuvb3l6mgeiR9G@iSojTEGaqwfWdvzetEdbg9xX80j65dav2Qpfw)) This will only check if the next `"` is followed by `HEX` and does not check for the opening `HEX "`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `tr` to convert newlines to spaces:

```
 tr '^M' ' '
```

eg:

```
echo "data1 HEX "This data2 should be\
in the same\
line" HEX data3" | tr '^M' ' '
```

To enter the newline `^M`, <kbd>control+V</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: this removes carriage returns (`\r`) rather than newlines (`\n`), and removes them from everywhere, not just in the place specified in the question

Comment: I think newline would be Ctrl-V Ctrl-J but you don't need to escape newlines inside sinqle-quotes anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
echo data1 HEX "This data2 should be
in the same
line" HEX data3 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**